# How can I automate "I am Groot" reply to annoying friend's texts?

Tags: iphone, applications, messages, automation

I kinda want to convey the point that all this individual's texts are just as meaningful as the phrase "I am Groot." Can this be done on my iPhone? That is, anytime I get a text from said individual, it will automatically reply "I am Groot."

Comment: This may have some useful info for you, just searched... : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/304944/237687

Comment: I have a copyright on the phrase “I am Groot.” Please change to some other nonsense phrase or face legal repercussions. In all seriousness, perhaps this question, in a different form, should be in Interpersonal.se because this is more of a problem between two _people_, and blocking the text, while satisfying to you, may not have the intended result. At some point, your idiotic interlocutor may at some point grow up and actually have something important to tell you.

Comment: I’ll put up a “nope” answer on the linked question. If you want to edit this to be a software recommendation question, please see [meta] for quidelines on asking a recommendation question.